# Inviting 5 friends out of 11 to dinner, with restriction

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm revising for finals and I have come across this following question:

> a) A woman has 11 close friends. Find the number of ways she can invite 5 of them to dinner.
>
> b) Repeat a) but 2 of the friends are married and will not attend separately.

For a) I got ${11 \choose 5} = \frac{11!}{(11-5)! \cdot 5!} = 462$.

I'm completely lost on b). I tried $n-2$ (minus two friends that are married) and then:
${9 \choose 5} = \frac{9!}{(9-5)! \cdot 5!} = 126$, but I'm pretty sure this is wrong,

Could someone explain b) to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** For (b), try subtracting from your answer to (a) all combinations of $5$ people that include *exactly* one of the two married friends.

Comment: 10!(5!x5!)=252
462-252=210. 
I get it Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

for part b,

the woman has 2 choices , either to invite the couple or not invite them ,

CASE1: she invites them

then she has to choose 3 friends out of 9 (2 out of 11 are already chosen), which she can do in ${9 \choose 3}$ ways

CASE2: when she doesnt invites the couple

then she has to choose 5 friends out of 9(2out of 11 are not to be chosen), which she can do in ${9 \choose 5}$ ways

Answer (score 1):

Originally, the possible invitees consisted of 11 units (each is one friend)
Now,since two of theme are married and will not be attending separately,
the possible invitees consist of 10 units (9 corresponding to one friend, and the last unit is the couple.)
Hence the no, of ways we can select 5 from 10 units is:
10C5, i.e., 210.

Comment: +1 : I'm glad that someone presented the *units* perspective.

Comment: You might want to double check your math, re computing $\binom{10}{5}.$